# Azure cloud shell: download command not working

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

It's been a while since I used az cloud shell's download command. It worked great when I first tried it.

Yesterday I had to download some files in my cs storage, but when trying to: `download somefile.ext`
, nothing happened! (tested w/ bash & powershell).

Inspecting the network tab I couldn't find any errors. All requests returned HTTP 200.

Am I doing something wrong?

ps: I'm using Chrome v83.0.4103.97.

---

UPDATE

@KrishnaG-MSFT, it is possible to download the files following the [mentioned document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#transfer-local-files-to-cloud-shell). The issue arises when I try to download using the `download` bash command.

@Charles Xu, see the screenshot below:

[image: az download command sample]

A) Works fine.

B) Download won't start.

---

UPDATE 2

Inspecting Chrome's console, I saw this message as soon I executed the command:

[image]
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280

MS Edge v83 yields the same result (expected, as it is also using Chromium), so the culprit seems to be the removal of a browser feature due to security reasons.

Comment: What do you mean about downloading the `somefile.ext`? Can you share the screenshot or details what do you do?

Comment: Both ways work fine on my side. You can check if something blocked in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue but have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage) Azure document and was able to successfully download the files that are persisted.

I recommend you to double check if you are trying to download files that are persisted as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#transfer-local-files-to-cloud-shell) and confirm if the issue still persists.